# Conflicting Wacom drivers?

Tags: drivers, xorg, wacom

Sometimes when plugging in my Wacom tablet, it works great. Other times, even though it is responsive, it is unusably buggy.

I can detect which situation I am in by running the command

```
$ xsetwacom --list
```

If I get the output (id's may change)

```
Wacom Intuos S Pad pad              id: 17  type: PAD       
Wacom Intuos S Pen stylus           id: 18  type: STYLUS    
Wacom Intuos S Pen eraser           id: 19  type: ERASER    
Wacom Intuos S Pen cursor           id: 20  type: CURSOR
```

then I know all is well. If instead I get

```
Wacom Co.,Ltd. Intuos S stylus      id: 17  type: STYLUS    
Wacom Co.,Ltd. Intuos S eraser      id: 18  type: ERASER
```

then I am in trouble. Unplugging the device and plugging it back in never seems to help go from bad to good, but does go the other way. Rebooting the system sometimes - but not always - solves the problem.

Are there two conflicting drivers between which the OS chooses? How can I force it to make the right choice?

edit: output of lsusb 'good situation'

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 056a:0374 Wacom Co., Ltd
```

output of lsusb 'bad situation'

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 2d1f:0374
```

Comment: What is the vid:pid of your device? (from lsusb)

Comment: @AaronSkomra added relevant info

Comment: There's some info for the 2nd vendor id [here](https://github.com/linuxwacom/libwacom/wiki/Troubleshooting) (last paragraph).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on your discovery and meuh's comment above, the tablet has two VID:PIDs. One for Android Mode, one for regular Linux mode. It is not ideal, but in order to switch in to the correct mode you need to hold down the buttons on both ends for a few seconds. More info here:

https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/wiki/Known-Issues#android-misdetect

Comment: Thanks for the info, that makes some amount of sense. So the problem is with the firmware of the tablet rather than with the configuration of the system, implying that there is nothing I can change to the latter to make this problem go away?

Comment: Unfortunately yes.